Integral solutions $(a,b)$ to equation $2\sqrt{ab-n} +b = a$ given positive integer $n$.
I've tried some algebraic manipulations for this equation but I cannot come up with nontrivial solutions for specific values of $n$. In particular, upon expansion and transposition, this leads to a form similar to the Pell equation. Moreover, I have found that $ab-n$ is necessarily a square and $(a,b)$ must be of the same parity. I will greatly appreciate any hint or suggestion that can be provided towards this problem.

You can write it as $(a-3b)^2-2(2b)^2=-4n$. So, it is the same as finding integer solutions for $x^2-2y^2=-4n$.

What is the equivalent Pell-equation if the expression in the radical is changed to $ab+n$?

By brute-forcing up to 100, I found that solutions exist for n = 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 14, 16, 17, 18, 23, 25, 28, 31, 32, 34, 36, 41, 46, 47, 49, 50, 56, 62, 63, 64, 68, 71, 72, 73, 79, 81, 82, 89, 92, 94, 97, 98, 100.

@Dan  yes, for legal $n$,   exponents on primes $2$   and $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$    are not restricted, but exponents on primes  $q \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$  must be even.  Also, negating $n$ is alright.

That is, for the equation to admit solutions $(a,b)$, then the exponent on the factorization of $n$ must satisfy your given conditions?

@numbergobbler  yes,  if and only if. Note:  in order to direct a comment to someone, begin it with an @  sign and a few letters of that username. Then a little flag will appear on that person's display, despite them having left this post for some other.

Worth showing you how the count of "fundamental solutions" changes as count of  prime factors of $n$  increases....That is, this is possible only when:  prime factors $2$ and any $ p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$  are unrestricted, but any  $ q \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$  are required to have even exponents.
Below I show computations for some eligible $n.$  Oh: a minus sign is allowed.  Quite long, you need to scroll down to get larger $|n|$
Once you have $x^2 - 2 y^2 = -n,$   find your $a,b$  by
$$  a = 2x + 3y \; , \; \; \;  b = y    $$
Let's see, for $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1$   we have
$$ x_{j+2} = 6 x_{j+1}  - x_j \; , \; \; y_{j+2} = 6 y_{j+1}  - y_j  $$
By the time we get to $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 84847$   we have
$$ x_{j+32} = 6 x_{j+16}  - x_j \; , \; \; y_{j+32} = 6 y_{j+16}  - y_j  $$
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  1 1

 x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1 

Fri 31 May 2024 10:33:54 AM PDT

1. x:  1 =   1       y: 0 =    SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  3 =  3      y: 2 =  2  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1 ,  0
3. x:  17 =  17      y: 12 =  2^2 3
4. x:  99 =  3^2 11      y: 70 =  2 5 7
5. x:  577 =  577      y: 408 =  2^3 3 17
6. x:  3363 =  3 19 59      y: 2378 =  2 29 41
7. x:  19601 =  17 1153      y: 13860 =  2^2 3^2 5 7 11
8. x:  114243 =  3 113 337      y: 80782 =  2 13^2 239
9. x:  665857 =  665857      y: 470832 =  2^4 3 17 577
10. x:  3880899 =  3^3 11 73 179      y: 2744210 =  2 5 7 197 199
=================================================
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  -1 1

 x^2 - 2 y^2 = -1  

Fri 31 May 2024 10:35:28 AM PDT

1. x:  1 =   1       y: 1 =   1   SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  7 =  7      y: 5 =  5
3. x:  41 =  41      y: 29 =  29
4. x:  239 =  239      y: 169 =  13^2
5. x:  1393 =  7 199      y: 985 =  5 197
6. x:  8119 =  23 353      y: 5741 =  5741
7. x:  47321 =  79 599      y: 33461 =  33461
8. x:  275807 =  7 31^2 41      y: 195025 =  5^2 29 269
9. x:  1607521 =  103 15607      y: 1136689 =  137 8297







===========================================================
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  7 1
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   4
    2   3


 x^2 - 2 y^2 = 7 =  7

Fri 31 May 2024 10:28:30 AM PDT

1. x:  3 =  3      y: 1 =   1   SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  5 =  5      y: 3 =  3  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  3 ,  -1
3. x:  13 =  13      y: 9 =  3^2
4. x:  27 =  3^3      y: 19 =  19
5. x:  75 =  3 5^2      y: 53 =  53
6. x:  157 =  157      y: 111 =  3 37
7. x:  437 =  19 23      y: 309 =  3 103
8. x:  915 =  3 5 61      y: 647 =  647
9. x:  2547 =  3^2 283      y: 1801 =  1801
10. x:  5333 =  5333      y: 3771 =  3^2 419
11. x:  14845 =  5 2969      y: 10497 =  3 3499
12. x:  31083 =  3 13 797      y: 21979 =  31 709
13. x:  86523 =  3 151 191      y: 61181 =  193 317
14. x:  181165 =  5 19 1907      y: 128103 =  3 42701
15. x:  504293 =  101 4993      y: 356589 =  3^3 47 281
16. x:  1055907 =  3^2 23 5101      y: 746639 =  149 5011
17. x:  2939235 =  3 5 13 15073      y: 2078353 =  19 109387
================================================================================
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  -7 1
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   4
    2   3

 x^2 - 2 y^2 = -7 =  -7

Fri 31 May 2024 10:30:18 AM PDT

1. x:  1 =   1       y: 2 =  2  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  5 =  5      y: 4 =  2^2  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -1 ,  2
3. x:  11 =  11      y: 8 =  2^3
4. x:  31 =  31      y: 22 =  2 11
5. x:  65 =  5 13      y: 46 =  2 23
6. x:  181 =  181      y: 128 =  2^7
7. x:  379 =  379      y: 268 =  2^2 67
8. x:  1055 =  5 211      y: 746 =  2 373
9. x:  2209 =  47^2      y: 1562 =  2 11 71
10. x:  6149 =  11 13 43      y: 4348 =  2^2 1087
11. x:  12875 =  5^3 103      y: 9104 =  2^4 569
12. x:  35839 =  35839      y: 25342 =  2 12671
13. x:  75041 =  75041      y: 53062 =  2 43 617
14. x:  208885 =  5 41777      y: 147704 =  2^3 37 499
15. x:  437371 =  11 39761      y: 309268 =  2^2 77317
16. x:  1217471 =  1217471      y: 860882 =  2 11 109 359
17. x:  2549185 =  5 509837      y: 1802546 =  2 901273
===================================================================================================

jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  119 1

 x^2 - 2 y^2 = 119 =  7 17

Fri 31 May 2024 10:32:31 AM PDT

1. x:  11 =  11      y: 1 =   1   SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  13 =  13      y: 5 =  5  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  19 =  19      y: 11 =  11  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  13 ,  -5
4. x:  29 =  29      y: 19 =  19  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  11 ,  -1
5. x:  37 =  37      y: 25 =  5^2
6. x:  59 =  59      y: 41 =  41
7. x:  101 =  101      y: 71 =  71
8. x:  163 =  163      y: 115 =  5 23
9. x:  211 =  211      y: 149 =  149
10. x:  341 =  11 31      y: 241 =  241
11. x:  587 =  587      y: 415 =  5 83
12. x:  949 =  13 73      y: 671 =  11 61
13. x:  1229 =  1229      y: 869 =  11 79
14. x:  1987 =  1987      y: 1405 =  5 281
15. x:  3421 =  11 311      y: 2419 =  41 59
16. x:  5531 =  5531      y: 3911 =  3911
17. x:  7163 =  13 19 29      y: 5065 =  5 1013
18. x:  11581 =  37 313      y: 8189 =  19 431
19. x:  19939 =  127 157      y: 14099 =  23 613
20. x:  32237 =  32237      y: 22795 =  5 47 97
21. x:  41749 =  83 503      y: 29521 =  53 557
22. x:  67499 =  67499      y: 47729 =  11 4339
23. x:  116213 =  251 463      y: 82175 =  5^2 19 173
24. x:  187891 =  11 19 29 31      y: 132859 =  132859
25. x:  243331 =  11^2 2011      y: 172061 =  73 2357
26. x:  393413 =  393413      y: 278185 =  5 23 41 59
==================================================================
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  -119 1

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = -119 =   -1 * 7 17

Fri 31 May 2024 10:36:41 AM PDT

1. x:  3 =  3      y: 8 =  2^3  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  9 =  3^2      y: 10 =  2 5  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  13 =  13      y: 12 =  2^2 3  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -9 ,  10
4. x:  23 =  23      y: 18 =  2 3^2  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -3 ,  8
5. x:  41 =  41      y: 30 =  2 3 5
6. x:  67 =  67      y: 48 =  2^4 3
7. x:  87 =  3 29      y: 62 =  2 31
8. x:  141 =  3 47      y: 100 =  2^2 5^2
9. x:  243 =  3^5      y: 172 =  2^2 43
10. x:  393 =  3 131      y: 278 =  2 139
11. x:  509 =  509      y: 360 =  2^3 3^2 5
12. x:  823 =  823      y: 582 =  2 3 97
13. x:  1417 =  13 109      y: 1002 =  2 3 167
14. x:  2291 =  29 79      y: 1620 =  2^2 3^4 5
15. x:  2967 =  3 23 43      y: 2098 =  2 1049
16. x:  4797 =  3^2 13 41      y: 3392 =  2^6 53
17. x:  8259 =  3 2753      y: 5840 =  2^4 5 73
18. x:  13353 =  3 4451      y: 9442 =  2 4721
19. x:  17293 =  17293      y: 12228 =  2^2 3 1019
20. x:  27959 =  73 383      y: 19770 =  2 3 5 659
21. x:  48137 =  37 1301      y: 34038 =  2 3^2 31 61
22. x:  77827 =  223 349      y: 55032 =  2^3 3 2293
23. x:  100791 =  3^3 3733      y: 71270 =  2 5 7127
24. x:  162957 =  3 54319      y: 115228 =  2^2 28807
25. x:  280563 =  3 41 2281      y: 198388 =  2^2 49597
26. x:  453609 =  3^2 13 3877      y: 320750 =  2 5^3 1283
27. x:  587453 =  29 47 431      y: 415392 =  2^5 3 4327
28. x:  949783 =  521 1823      y: 671598 =  2 3^3 12437
29. x:  1635241 =  1635241      y: 1156290 =  2 3 5 38543
30. x:  2643827 =  23 71 1619      y: 1869468 =  2^2 3 43 3623
31. x:  3423927 =  3 13 87793      y: 2421082 =  2 1210541
===============================================================================
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  2737 1

 x^2 - 2 y^2 = 2737 =  7 17 23

Fri 31 May 2024 10:38:11 AM PDT

1. x:  53 =  53      y: 6 =  2 3  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  55 =  5 11      y: 12 =  2^2 3  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  57 =  3 19      y: 16 =  2^4  SEED   KEEP +- 
4. x:  73 =  73      y: 36 =  2^2 3^2  SEED   KEEP +- 
5. x:  75 =  3 5^2      y: 38 =  2 19  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  73 ,  -36
6. x:  107 =  107      y: 66 =  2 3 11  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  57 ,  -16
7. x:  117 =  3^2 13      y: 74 =  2 37  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  55 ,  -12
8. x:  135 =  3^3 5      y: 88 =  2^3 11  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  53 ,  -6
9. x:  183 =  3 61      y: 124 =  2^2 31
10. x:  213 =  3 71      y: 146 =  2 73
11. x:  235 =  5 47      y: 162 =  2 3^4
12. x:  363 =  3 11^2      y: 254 =  2 127
13. x:  377 =  13 29      y: 264 =  2^3 3 11
14. x:  585 =  3^2 5 13      y: 412 =  2^2 103
15. x:  647 =  647      y: 456 =  2^3 3 19
16. x:  757 =  757      y: 534 =  2 3 89
17. x:  1045 =  5 11 19      y: 738 =  2 3^2 41
18. x:  1223 =  1223      y: 864 =  2^5 3^3
19. x:  1353 =  3 11 41      y: 956 =  2^2 239
20. x:  2105 =  5 421      y: 1488 =  2^4 3 31
21. x:  2187 =  3^7      y: 1546 =  2 773
22. x:  3403 =  41 83      y: 2406 =  2 3 401
23. x:  3765 =  3 5 251      y: 2662 =  2 11^3
24. x:  4407 =  3 13 113      y: 3116 =  2^2 19 41
25. x:  6087 =  3 2029      y: 4304 =  2^4 269
26. x:  7125 =  3 5^3 19      y: 5038 =  2 11 229
27. x:  7883 =  7883      y: 5574 =  2 3 929
28. x:  12267 =  3^2 29 47      y: 8674 =  2 4337
29. x:  12745 =  5 2549      y: 9012 =  2^2 3 751
30. x:  19833 =  3 11 601      y: 14024 =  2^3 1753
31. x:  21943 =  21943      y: 15516 =  2^2 3^2 431
32. x:  25685 =  5 11 467      y: 18162 =  2 3^2 1009
33. x:  35477 =  13 2729      y: 25086 =  2 3 37 113
34. x:  41527 =  131 317      y: 29364 =  2^2 3 2447
35. x:  45945 =  3^2 5 1021      y: 32488 =  2^3 31 131
36. x:  71497 =  19 53 71      y: 50556 =  2^2 3 11 383
37. x:  74283 =  3 11 2251      y: 52526 =  2 26263
38. x:  115595 =  5 61 379      y: 81738 =  2 3^2 19 239
39. x:  127893 =  3 89 479      y: 90434 =  2 103 439
40. x:  149703 =  3 139 359      y: 105856 =  2^7 827
41. x:  206775 =  3^2 5^2 919      y: 146212 =  2^2 11 3323
42. x:  242037 =  3^2 26893      y: 171146 =  2 83 1031
43. x:  267787 =  13 20599      y: 189354 =  2 3 11 19 151
44. x:  416715 =  3 5 13 2137      y: 294662 =  2 147331
45. x:  432953 =  19 22787      y: 306144 =  2^5 3^2 1063
46. x:  673737 =  3 224579      y: 476404 =  2^2 119101
47. x:  745415 =  5 11 13553      y: 527088 =  2^4 3 79 139
48. x:  872533 =  872533      y: 616974 =  2 3 102829
49. x:  1205173 =  1205173      y: 852186 =  2 3 142031
50. x:  1410695 =  5 11 13 1973      y: 997512 =  2^3 3 89 467
51. x:  1560777 =  3 223 2333      y: 1103636 =  2^2 37 7457
52. x:  2428793 =  107 22699      y: 1717416 =  2^3 3^3 7951
53. x:  2523435 =  3 5 29 5801      y: 1784338 =  2 892169
54. x:  3926827 =  3926827      y: 2776686 =  2 3 11 42071
=============================================================================

jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  -2737 1

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = -2737 =   -1 * 7 17 23

Fri 31 May 2024 10:39:39 AM PDT

1. x:  1 =   1       y: 37 =  37  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  25 =  5^2      y: 41 =  41  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  31 =  31      y: 43 =  43  SEED   KEEP +- 
4. x:  41 =  41      y: 47 =  47  SEED   KEEP +- 
5. x:  65 =  5 13      y: 59 =  59  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -41 ,  47
6. x:  79 =  79      y: 67 =  67  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -31 ,  43
7. x:  89 =  89      y: 73 =  73  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -25 ,  41
8. x:  145 =  5 29      y: 109 =  109  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -1 ,  37
9. x:  151 =  151      y: 113 =  113
10. x:  239 =  239      y: 173 =  173
11. x:  265 =  5 53      y: 191 =  191
12. x:  311 =  311      y: 223 =  223
13. x:  431 =  431      y: 307 =  307
14. x:  505 =  5 101      y: 359 =  359
15. x:  559 =  13 43      y: 397 =  397
16. x:  871 =  13 67      y: 617 =  617
17. x:  905 =  5 181      y: 641 =  641
18. x:  1409 =  1409      y: 997 =  997
19. x:  1559 =  1559      y: 1103 =  1103
20. x:  1825 =  5^2 73      y: 1291 =  1291
21. x:  2521 =  2521      y: 1783 =  1783
22. x:  2951 =  13 227      y: 2087 =  2087
23. x:  3265 =  5 653      y: 2309 =  2309
24. x:  5081 =  5081      y: 3593 =  3593
25. x:  5279 =  5279      y: 3733 =  3733
26. x:  8215 =  5 31 53      y: 5809 =  37 157
27. x:  9089 =  61 149      y: 6427 =  6427
28. x:  10639 =  10639      y: 7523 =  7523
29. x:  14695 =  5 2939      y: 10391 =  10391
30. x:  17201 =  103 167      y: 12163 =  12163
31. x:  19031 =  19031      y: 13457 =  13457
32. x:  29615 =  5 5923      y: 20941 =  43 487
33. x:  30769 =  29 1061      y: 21757 =  21757
34. x:  47881 =  47881      y: 33857 =  33857
35. x:  52975 =  5^2 13 163      y: 37459 =  47 797
36. x:  62009 =  59 1051      y: 43847 =  163 269
37. x:  85649 =  41 2089      y: 60563 =  71 853
38. x:  100255 =  5 20051      y: 70891 =  70891
39. x:  110921 =  110921      y: 78433 =  41 1913
40. x:  172609 =  101 1709      y: 122053 =  122053
41. x:  179335 =  5 13 31 89      y: 126809 =  173 733
42. x:  279071 =  13 21467      y: 197333 =  41 4813
43. x:  308761 =  308761      y: 218327 =  109 2003
44. x:  361415 =  5 41^2 43      y: 255559 =  37 6907
45. x:  499199 =  59 8461      y: 352987 =  43 8209
46. x:  584329 =  499 1171      y: 413183 =  413183
47. x:  646495 =  5 239 541      y: 457141 =  67 6823
48. x:  1006039 =  29 113 307      y: 711377 =  89 7993
49. x:  1045241 =  1045241      y: 739097 =  479 1543
50. x:  1626545 =  5 325309      y: 1150141 =  1150141
51. x:  1799591 =  1799591      y: 1272503 =  419 3037
52. x:  2106481 =  13 31 5227      y: 1489507 =  1489507
53. x:  2909545 =  5 581909      y: 2057359 =  73 28183
54. x:  3405719 =  509 6691      y: 2408207 =  601 4007
55. x:  3768049 =  103 36583      y: 2664413 =  857 3109
==========================================================================

jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  84847 1


 x^2 - 2 y^2 = 84847 =  7 17 23 31

Fri 31 May 2024 10:40:53 AM PDT

1. x:  295 =  5 59      y: 33 =  3 11  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  297 =  3^3 11      y: 41 =  41  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  303 =  3 101      y: 59 =  59  SEED   KEEP +- 
4. x:  313 =  313      y: 81 =  3^4  SEED   KEEP +- 
5. x:  335 =  5 67      y: 117 =  3^2 13  SEED   KEEP +- 
6. x:  353 =  353      y: 141 =  3 47  SEED   KEEP +- 
7. x:  375 =  3 5^3      y: 167 =  167  SEED   KEEP +- 
8. x:  407 =  11 37      y: 201 =  3 67  SEED   KEEP +- 
9. x:  417 =  3 139      y: 211 =  211  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  407 ,  -201
10. x:  457 =  457      y: 249 =  3 83  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  375 ,  -167
11. x:  495 =  3^2 5 11      y: 283 =  283  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  353 ,  -141
12. x:  537 =  3 179      y: 319 =  11 29  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  335 ,  -117
13. x:  615 =  3 5 41      y: 383 =  383  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  313 ,  -81
14. x:  673 =  673      y: 429 =  3 11 13  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  303 ,  -59
15. x:  727 =  727      y: 471 =  3 157  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  297 ,  -41
16. x:  753 =  3 251      y: 491 =  491  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  295 ,  -33
17. x:  1017 =  3^2 113      y: 689 =  13 53
18. x:  1055 =  5 211      y: 717 =  3 239
19. x:  1145 =  5 229      y: 783 =  3^3 29
20. x:  1263 =  3 421      y: 869 =  11 79
21. x:  1473 =  3 491      y: 1021 =  1021
22. x:  1623 =  3 541      y: 1129 =  1129
23. x:  1793 =  11 163      y: 1251 =  3^2 139
24. x:  2025 =  3^4 5^2      y: 1417 =  13 109
25. x:  2095 =  5 419      y: 1467 =  3^2 163
26. x:  2367 =  3^2 263      y: 1661 =  11 151
27. x:  2617 =  2617      y: 1839 =  3 613
28. x:  2887 =  2887      y: 2031 =  3 677
29. x:  3377 =  11 307      y: 2379 =  3 13 61
30. x:  3735 =  3^2 5 83      y: 2633 =  2633
31. x:  4065 =  3 5 271      y: 2867 =  47 61
32. x:  4223 =  41 103      y: 2979 =  3^2 331
33. x:  5807 =  5807      y: 4101 =  3 1367
34. x:  6033 =  3 2011      y: 4261 =  4261
35. x:  6567 =  3 11 199      y: 4639 =  4639
36. x:  7265 =  5 1453      y: 5133 =  3 29 59
37. x:  8503 =  11 773      y: 6009 =  3 2003
38. x:  9385 =  5 1877      y: 6633 =  3^2 11 67
39. x:  10383 =  3 3461      y: 7339 =  41 179
40. x:  11743 =  11743      y: 8301 =  3 2767
41. x:  12153 =  3 4051      y: 8591 =  11^2 71
42. x:  13745 =  5 2749      y: 9717 =  3 41 79
43. x:  15207 =  3 37 137      y: 10751 =  13 827
44. x:  16785 =  3^2 5 373      y: 11867 =  11867
45. x:  19647 =  3^2 37 59      y: 13891 =  29 479
46. x:  21737 =  21737      y: 15369 =  3 47 109
47. x:  23663 =  23663      y: 16731 =  3^2 11 13^2
48. x:  24585 =  3 5 11 149      y: 17383 =  17383
49. x:  33825 =  3 5^2 11 41      y: 23917 =  23917
50. x:  35143 =  113 311      y: 24849 =  3^2 11 251
51. x:  38257 =  67 571      y: 27051 =  3 71 127
52. x:  42327 =  3^2 4703      y: 29929 =  173^2
53. x:  49545 =  3^3 5 367      y: 35033 =  53 661
54. x:  54687 =  3 18229      y: 38669 =  38669
55. x:  60505 =  5 12101      y: 42783 =  3 13 1097
=====================================================================

jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  -84847 1

 x^2 - 2 y^2 = -84847 =   -1 * 7 17 23 31

Fri 31 May 2024 10:42:08 AM PDT

1. x:  5 =  5      y: 206 =  2 103  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  41 =  41      y: 208 =  2^4 13  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  71 =  71      y: 212 =  2^2 53  SEED   KEEP +- 
4. x:  101 =  101      y: 218 =  2 109  SEED   KEEP +- 
5. x:  151 =  151      y: 232 =  2^3 29  SEED   KEEP +- 
6. x:  185 =  5 37      y: 244 =  2^2 61  SEED   KEEP +- 
7. x:  215 =  5 43      y: 256 =  2^8  SEED   KEEP +- 
8. x:  229 =  229      y: 262 =  2 131  SEED   KEEP +- 
9. x:  361 =  19^2      y: 328 =  2^3 41  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -229 ,  262
10. x:  379 =  379      y: 338 =  2 13^2  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -215 ,  256
11. x:  421 =  421      y: 362 =  2 181  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -185 ,  244
12. x:  475 =  5^2 19      y: 394 =  2 197  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -151 ,  232
13. x:  569 =  569      y: 452 =  2^2 113  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -101 ,  218
14. x:  635 =  5 127      y: 494 =  2 13 19  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -71 ,  212
15. x:  709 =  709      y: 542 =  2 271  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -41 ,  208
16. x:  809 =  809      y: 608 =  2^5 19  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -5 ,  206
17. x:  839 =  839      y: 628 =  2^2 157
18. x:  955 =  5 191      y: 706 =  2 353
19. x:  1061 =  1061      y: 778 =  2 389
20. x:  1175 =  5^2 47      y: 856 =  2^3 107
21. x:  1381 =  1381      y: 998 =  2 499
22. x:  1531 =  1531      y: 1102 =  2 19 29
23. x:  1669 =  1669      y: 1198 =  2 599
24. x:  1735 =  5 347      y: 1244 =  2^2 311
25. x:  2395 =  5 479      y: 1706 =  2 853
26. x:  2489 =  19 131      y: 1772 =  2^2 443
27. x:  2711 =  2711      y: 1928 =  2^3 241
28. x:  3001 =  3001      y: 2132 =  2^2 13 41
29. x:  3515 =  5 19 37      y: 2494 =  2 29 43
30. x:  3881 =  3881      y: 2752 =  2^6 43
31. x:  4295 =  5 859      y: 3044 =  2^2 761
32. x:  4859 =  43 113      y: 3442 =  2 1721
33. x:  5029 =  47 107      y: 3562 =  2 13 137
34. x:  5689 =  5689      y: 4028 =  2^2 19 53
35. x:  6295 =  5 1259      y: 4456 =  2^3 557
36. x:  6949 =  6949      y: 4918 =  2 2459
37. x:  8135 =  5 1627      y: 5756 =  2^2 1439
38. x:  9001 =  9001      y: 6368 =  2^5 199
39. x:  9799 =  41 239      y: 6932 =  2^2 1733
40. x:  10181 =  10181      y: 7202 =  2 13 277
41. x:  14009 =  14009      y: 9908 =  2^2 2477
42. x:  14555 =  5 41 71      y: 10294 =  2 5147
43. x:  15845 =  5 3169      y: 11206 =  2 13 431
44. x:  17531 =  47 373      y: 12398 =  2 6199
45. x:  20521 =  20521      y: 14512 =  2^4 907
46. x:  22651 =  22651      y: 16018 =  2 8009
47. x:  25061 =  19 1319      y: 17722 =  2 8861
48. x:  28345 =  5 5669      y: 20044 =  2^2 5011
49. x:  29335 =  5 5867      y: 20744 =  2^3 2593
50. x:  33179 =  33179      y: 23462 =  2 11731
51. x:  36709 =  36709      y: 25958 =  2 12979
52. x:  40519 =  40519      y: 28652 =  2^2 13 19 29
53. x:  47429 =  43 1103      y: 33538 =  2 41 409
54. x:  52475 =  5^2 2099      y: 37106 =  2 18553
55. x:  57125 =  5^3 457      y: 40394 =  2 19 1063
================================================================================

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
For this one
$$ x_{j+64} = 6 x_{j+32}  - x_j \; , \; \; y_{j+64} = 6 y_{j+32}  - y_j  $$
./Pell_Target_Fundamental  2  3 2  3478727 10 

 x^2 - 2 y^2 = 3478727 =  7 17 23 31 41

Fri 31 May 2024 01:17:56 PM PDT

1. x:  1867 =  1867      y: 59 =  59  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  1877 =  1877      y: 149 =  149  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  1885 =  5 13 29      y: 193 =  193  SEED   KEEP +- 
4. x:  1907 =  1907      y: 281 =  281  SEED   KEEP +- 
5. x:  1915 =  5 383      y: 307 =  307  SEED   KEEP +- 
6. x:  1933 =  1933      y: 359 =  359  SEED   KEEP +- 
7. x:  1957 =  19 103      y: 419 =  419  SEED   KEEP +- 
8. x:  2045 =  5 409      y: 593 =  593  SEED   KEEP +- 
9. x:  2075 =  5^2 83      y: 643 =  643  SEED   KEEP +- 
10. x:  2197 =  13^3      y: 821 =  821  SEED   KEEP +- 
11. x:  2203 =  2203      y: 829 =  829  SEED   KEEP +- 
12. x:  2243 =  2243      y: 881 =  881  SEED   KEEP +- 
13. x:  2333 =  2333      y: 991 =  991  SEED   KEEP +- 
14. x:  2357 =  2357      y: 1019 =  1019  SEED   KEEP +- 
15. x:  2483 =  13 191      y: 1159 =  19 61  SEED   KEEP +- 
16. x:  2515 =  5 503      y: 1193 =  1193  SEED   KEEP +- 
17. x:  2773 =  47 59      y: 1451 =  1451  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2515 ,  -1193
18. x:  2813 =  29 97      y: 1489 =  1489  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2483 ,  -1159
19. x:  2995 =  5 599      y: 1657 =  1657  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2357 ,  -1019
20. x:  3035 =  5 607      y: 1693 =  1693  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2333 ,  -991
21. x:  3205 =  5 641      y: 1843 =  19 97  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2243 ,  -881
22. x:  3293 =  37 89      y: 1919 =  19 101  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2203 ,  -829
23. x:  3307 =  3307      y: 1931 =  1931  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2197 ,  -821
24. x:  3653 =  13 281      y: 2221 =  2221  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2075 ,  -643
25. x:  3763 =  53 71      y: 2311 =  2311  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  2045 ,  -593
26. x:  4195 =  5 839      y: 2657 =  2657  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1957 ,  -419
27. x:  4363 =  4363      y: 2789 =  2789  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1933 ,  -359
28. x:  4517 =  4517      y: 2909 =  2909  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1915 ,  -307
29. x:  4597 =  4597      y: 2971 =  2971  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1907 ,  -281
30. x:  4883 =  19 257      y: 3191 =  3191  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1885 ,  -193
31. x:  5035 =  5 19 53      y: 3307 =  3307  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1877 ,  -149
32. x:  5365 =  5 29 37      y: 3557 =  3557  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1867 ,  -59
33. x:  5837 =  13 449      y: 3911 =  3911
34. x:  6227 =  13 479      y: 4201 =  4201
35. x:  6427 =  6427      y: 4349 =  4349
36. x:  6845 =  5 37^2      y: 4657 =  4657
37. x:  6973 =  19 367      y: 4751 =  4751
38. x:  7235 =  5 1447      y: 4943 =  4943
39. x:  7547 =  7547      y: 5171 =  5171
40. x:  8507 =  47 181      y: 5869 =  5869
41. x:  8797 =  19 463      y: 6079 =  6079
42. x:  9875 =  5^3 79      y: 6857 =  6857
43. x:  9925 =  5^2 397      y: 6893 =  61 113
44. x:  10253 =  10253      y: 7129 =  7129
45. x:  10963 =  19 577      y: 7639 =  7639
46. x:  11147 =  71 157      y: 7771 =  19 409
47. x:  12085 =  5 2417      y: 8443 =  8443
48. x:  12317 =  109 113      y: 8609 =  8609
49. x:  14123 =  29 487      y: 9899 =  19 521
50. x:  14395 =  5 2879      y: 10093 =  10093
51. x:  15613 =  13 1201      y: 10961 =  97 113
52. x:  15877 =  15877      y: 11149 =  11149
53. x:  16987 =  16987      y: 11939 =  11939
54. x:  17555 =  5 3511      y: 12343 =  12343
55. x:  17645 =  5 3529      y: 12407 =  19 653
56. x:  19843 =  19843      y: 13969 =  61 229
57. x:  20533 =  20533      y: 14459 =  19 761
58. x:  23213 =  139 167      y: 16361 =  16361
59. x:  24245 =  5 13 373      y: 17093 =  17093
60. x:  25187 =  89 283      y: 17761 =  17761
61. x:  25675 =  5^2 13 79      y: 18107 =  19 953
62. x:  27413 =  79 347      y: 19339 =  83 233
63. x:  28333 =  29 977      y: 19991 =  19991
64. x:  30323 =  30323      y: 21401 =  21401
65. x:  33155 =  5 19 349      y: 23407 =  89 263
66. x:  35485 =  5 47 151      y: 25057 =  25057
67. x:  36677 =  36677      y: 25901 =  59 439
68. x:  39163 =  39163      y: 27661 =  139 199
69. x:  39923 =  13 37 83      y: 28199 =  163 173
70. x:  41477 =  19 37 59      y: 29299 =  83 353
71. x:  43325 =  5^2 1733      y: 30607 =  127 241
72. x:  48997 =  13 3769      y: 34621 =  89 389
73. x:  50707 =  50707      y: 35831 =  35831
74. x:  57053 =  59 967      y: 40321 =  61 661
75. x:  57347 =  57347      y: 40529 =  40529
76. x:  59275 =  5^2 2371      y: 41893 =  41893
77. x:  63445 =  5 12689      y: 44843 =  44843
78. x:  64525 =  5^2 29 89      y: 45607 =  59 773
79. x:  70027 =  239 293      y: 49499 =  49499
80. x:  71387 =  71387      y: 50461 =  50461
81. x:  81965 =  5 13^2 97      y: 57943 =  57943
82. x:  83557 =  83557      y: 59069 =  59069
83. x:  90683 =  29 53 59      y: 64109 =  64109
84. x:  92227 =  92227      y: 65201 =  113 577
85. x:  98717 =  98717      y: 69791 =  101 691
86. x:  102037 =  13 47 167      y: 72139 =  72139
87. x:  102563 =  102563      y: 72511 =  59 1229
88. x:  115405 =  5 23081      y: 81593 =  139 587
89. x:  119435 =  5 23887      y: 84443 =  84443
90. x:  135083 =  13 10391      y: 95509 =  149 641
91. x:  141107 =  141107      y: 99769 =  19 59 89
92. x:  146605 =  5 109 269      y: 103657 =  103657
93. x:  149453 =  103 1451      y: 105671 =  251 421
94. x:  159595 =  5 59 541      y: 112843 =  112843
95. x:  164963 =  164963      y: 116639 =  116639
96. x:  176573 =  176573      y: 124849 =  19 6571
97. x:  193093 =  193093      y: 136531 =  136531
98. x:  206683 =  29 7127      y: 146141 =  146141
99. x:  213635 =  5 42727      y: 151057 =  151057
100. x:  228133 =  19 12007      y: 161309 =  161309

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$f(x)=6f(x-1)-f(x-2)$ for $x>2$
the solutions here are $(a,b)=(f(x+1),f(x))$ for $x>0$
depending on $n$:
$n=1: f(1)=1 ; f(2)=5$
$n=2: f(1)=1 ; f(2)=3$
$n=3:$ no solutions
$n=4: f(1)=2 ; f(2)=10$
$n=5 and n=6:$ no solutions
$n=7:$ you can start with $\{f(1)=4  \ and \ f(2)=22\}$ or $\{f(1)=2\ and \ f(2)=8\}$
$n=8: f(1)=2 ; f(2)=6$
$n=9: f(1)=3 ; f(2)=15$
this is my first time answering so I hope i'm clear. I don't know the rigourous solution for all n, but this is what I got with a bit of coding. try the solutions if you want!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

There is nothing unclear in this partial solution. It is given in one of the typical ways to give solutions to (generalized) Pell's equations, as an order 2 recurrence. It is just a partial solution.

MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference
